# source not found when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm using the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (Mac OS X 64 Bit) to debug my two java documents. I have a `Name` class with a method named `insert`. It executes but gives wrong result. `NamesTester` is test class for `Name` class.

During debug, when I using step into the `insert` method, it jumps to a strange document named `ArrayList<E>.size()`, and it shows Source not found. I don't know what's wrong. Does it means I can not step into a method to see what is happening there? But if I use step over, it's debugging next steps fine.

Can someone help me in finding the reason and solution? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For anybody to help you, you need to edit your post to include the source code that is causing a problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison, why is source code needed for above question? source code related to what are you trying to ask?

Comment: It makes all the difference in the world.  If I could see the source I could point to exactly WHY he's jumping into `ArrayList.size()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you jumped into a class definition your project classpath has no access to. For example Java JVM source code.
In your case, perhaps it tried to jump into ArrayList definition.

Look out thru google about debugging in eclipse, step into and step thru

Answer (score 1):

1. click `Attach source`
2. Check `External locations` and click `External files`
3. add `src.zip` from Program Files/java/jdk1.x/src.zip

Answer (score 0):

You debugged into the Java runtime code, but you don't have its sources installed on your machine. The most simple way to avoid that in the future is to install a full Java development kit (JDK) instead of only a Java runtime environment (JRE) and to make sure that Eclipse uses that JDK.

Comment: Yes I forgot to install JDK. Then I downloaded this: jdk-7u7-macosx-x64.dmg and installed it. But it seems nothing changed. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The method you pointing to ArrayList.size() , is a method of ArrayList class of jdk.

First : source not found is not an error. 
source not found comes when you are in debug mode and while debug you enter some class whose .java file is not located on classpath. This message just means that , the part of code you are trying to debu, source cide for that is not available and thus the debugger cant show the highlighted line etc. 
Now to correct this, i mean be able to see that method in your debugger, download the source code for jdk(the same version that you are using currently) and when you see the source not found screen , there is a atrach source button.select that and select the source code file you have downloaded and press ok.  and tge screen will refresh with the highlighted line of the class.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But when I try to fix it, I mean when I see the source not found screen, I click the Edit source lookup path, and added my source code file. But where is nothing changed. I don't know why.

Comment: I see only one possible reason , tge source file is not a source file. Is that file a .java file ??

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to attach source code to the library, this will help the debugger to find it.

follow this [thread](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jarsource) section 16.2,

hope this will help you.

Comment: Brother dont provide a complete doc for a simple answer. Simillarly we.can provide java doc to most of the questions here. Atleast mention the section name. I think its section 16.2 you are trying to mention.